# Return key, value and assign to dictionary in one line in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, return

I have a function which executes a job and return job id and whether it was successfull. Then I need to store these results in a dict. Currently I do this:

```
jobs_results = {}

...

job_id, job_result = execute_function()
jobs_results[job_id] = job_result
```

However, I was wondering if there is a way to turn these two lines into an oneliner, or if this is the Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Even if it is possible with some of the answers below, I would not recommend you to use many one-liners as these ones. Just remember the following [**Zen of Python**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) lines: "*Beautiful is better than ugly*", "*Explicit is better than implicit*" and "*If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your dictionary with a tuple of tuples,

```
jobs_results.update((execute_function(),))
```

or just assign it as a tuple of tuples

```
job_results = dict((execute_function(),))
```

I'd prefer your current approach though as its clearer

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `dict` from your function and then use `dict.update`

**Ex:**

```
def execute_function():
    ....
    return {job_id: job_result}

jobs_results.update(execute_function())
```